# URL parameter in django

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
return redirect('shops:edit_shop', details['bio'])
```

basically it redirects to `edit_shop` view with one `url` parameter `bio` whose value is **Testing Instagram API**.

and this is my view:

```
def edit_shop_page(request, bio):
print bio
return render(request, 'shops/profile/edit_form.html')
```

To my surprise, that `print bio` part is printing only the first word, i.e the word **Testing**.

In short, I sent a parameter with value **Testing Instagram API** and received only **Testing**.

Why is it so? How can I fix this?

Relevant part of `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^edit-shop/(?P<bio>[\w_.]+)', edit_shop_page, name='edit_shop'),
```

Comment: Seems you are using routes to breakdown the `bio` param part, maybe it split the words that have space in them, you could post your urls.py for us to see the regex

Comment: Do you really mean HTTP *GET* parameters? `redirect()` (and transitively `reverse()`) handle ` urls.py` parameters, not HTTP GET query strings

Comment: @bakkal  I posted the urls.py

Comment: @dhke, you are right. I am sorry I got confused. I will edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url(r'^edit-shop/(?P<bio>[\w_.]+)', edit_shop_page, name='edit_shop'),
```

Your regex will break the word after the first space, try allow a space too, e.g.

```
url(r'^edit-shop/(?P<bio>[\w ]+)', edit_shop_page, name='edit_shop'),
```